# Is uploading / updating Web.config a good way to change trace level of System.Diagnostic tracing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api

Generally, I would inject TraceListeners and adjust trace level through app.config and Web.config. And I understand that IIS will restart the Web app after the Web.config is updated and the last HTTP request is done and new HTTP requests will be pending before the new instance is created. I have been doing this for years no problem.

However, if I deploy the Web app to Azure managed services, or I have many (clustered) instances of the Web app, I am not sure if updating / uploading Web.config to each instance is still a good practice? Is there some alternative/better method to change the trace level for System.Diagnostics.TraceListeners?

And what if I deploy to AWS or alike for clustered services?

Answer (score 1):

You got it right! updating / uploading Web.config to each instance is not bad but could be tedious task,or error prone approach. Rather,

Would recommend to go with Application Insights,an extensible analytics service that monitors your live web application.

Just install a small instrumentation package in your application, and set up an Application Insights resource in the Microsoft Azure portal.

Performance impact would be minimal as,tracking calls are non-blocking, and are batched ; sent in a separate thread.

Telemetry types such as 'Exception traces from both server and client', 'Diagnostic log traces' and many more helps you understand how your app is performing and how it's being used.

Also you can perform Diagnostic search on instances of requests, exceptions, custom events, log traces, page views, dependency and AJAX calls.

For more information do read : [Application Insights - introduction](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-insights-overview/)

Thanks,
Kasam Shaikh

Comment: And what if I deploy to AWS or alike for clustered services?